# Are there any advantages to having more than one character?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I'm thinking about starting a twink in Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn.

The classsystem allows to level every class and every job with only one character. But I'm curious about it that there are so many slots to create more characters while you only really need one.

Are there any benefits in creating more characters for other jobs / classes or doesn't really matter if you level everything on one character?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no mechanical benefit to having multiple characters. A few intangible benefits do exist, such as being able to try out the other starting nations' introductory quests, or try out a different race or gender.

Conversely, there are a number of benefits to leveling multiple classes on a single character. Due to the way the cross-class skill system is designed, leveling up multiple classes on a single character is highly beneficial. A character that largely focuses on a single class/job (leveling other classes only to the minimum required to unlock their preferred job) won't have access to important cross-class skills that can be extremely important, especially in higher-level content.

Additionally, when playing on a class that's lower-level than your highest-level class, you receive a 50% bonus to experience gained.

Comment: *"when playing on a class that's lower-level than your highest-level class, you receive a 50% bonus to experience gained"* - I thought I read in the hint system that the size of the bonus depends on the level of your highest-level class, not a fixed-50%.

Comment: As far as I've ever seen, it's always 50% (and a quick Google search _seemed_ to back that up when I wrote that?), but I'd be happy to revise that if it's actually incorrect.

Comment: I've opened a new question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162097)

Comment: Another benefit to having only one character is a lower monthly subscription fee, but this must be explicitly chosen at your Mog Station.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason someone would create a new character is not to experience another class's introductory quests, but because **leveling up a new character is significantly more fun than leveling up a new class**.

Doing class-quests + hunting logs + unfinished guildquests will get you to about level 22 on a second-class, after which you need to level up by grinding FATEs + guildquests + levequests.  Given that [level 22 is only about 5% of the total XP you need for level 50](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Experience_Points/Chart), that means you need to earn almost 95% of your experience through tedious grinding.

In contrast, if you create a new character you can level up to 50 mostly through story-quests and side-quests.

---

Another reason someone might create a second character is to play on a different server *(if, for instance, they have friends who already have characters there)*.

Answer (score 0):

You would have more retainer slots to sell things, but that is mitigated slightly with the ability to purchase 2 additional retainers for $2/mo added on to your subscription.

You could also get around some timers, like the timeworn maps.

Comment: The counter argument to making more same-server chars just for the retainer, is the non-trivial time it takes to get that char through the story to the point where you get retainer access. Also the still (nearly 1y after launch) inability to move items or gil between characters on your same account (cant mail because cant friend offline people)

Comment: There is the ability to use a Free Company chest to transfer, or a friend.  I know of someone in a Free Company of one for that purpose.

But you are correct, that hurdle is not very trivial to overcome.