# Is the "Armoury" bonus XP for other classes level-dependent or a fixed 50%?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

According the in-game docs, the "Armory bonus XP" for lower-level classes depends on the level difference between that class and your main class.

[image: Armoury Bonus]

However, [many places](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/678050-final-fantasy-xiv-online-a-realm-reborn/67054034) *(including [another answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/161836/2578))* claim that's incorrect and the bonus is always a fixed 50%.

---

A quick Google search gives a lot of conflicting information.  For instance, [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/1qlgm6/high_level_bonus_xp/cde4vvm):

> It is a flat 50% bonus to all but your single highest DoW/DoM class.
>   The pop-up that explains the armoury bonus does say the level difference determines the bonus, it lied.

And [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/1nscbb/armoury_bonus_waiting_to_50/cclk6mv):

> The Armory XP bonus caps at 50%. It's possible to hit this cap with a relatively small difference in levels.

And [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/ffxiv/comments/1nscbb/armoury_bonus_waiting_to_50/ccljrs8):

> It's 50% bonus if they're > 2 levels lower than your highest, if they're < 2 levels it's 20%.

None of them provide any sources.

---

Does anyone have any **authoritative source** on the matter?
Or better yet, has anyone **Used Their Science!!!™** to figure it out?

Comment: The next time I don't have rested xp I'll have to check for sure...I have always just understood it to be a flat 50% though.

Comment: The help dialog didn't really lie to anyone per say, but rather it's referring about the amount of EXP you get rather than the percentage. In my experience it's a flat 50% until your second highest combat class matches your (previously) highest combat class level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of patch 3.0, the experience bonus is a flat +100% when on a job below level 50, and +50% between levels 50 and 60.

From the 3.0 patch notes:

[image: Screenshot of the patch notes showing this change]

As always, this bonus is only active if you're playing a class/job that is *lower level* than your highest-level class/job.

Answer (score 1):

It is a flat 50%. I believe that the older comments that allude to it scaling up based on level are either based on 1.0 information or possible design that has since changed.

(Source: Personal experience in 2.1 and onward, both at sub-50 [Arcanist 30, leveling Conjurer and Thaumaturge] and at-50 [Arcanist 50, leveling Lancer and Archer].)